# Review queues on documentation

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, documentation

I have seen documentation today, and I love it. But, on AskUbuntu, I do a lot of reviewing on the First Posts and Late Answers queues. So I was horrified when in most topic near the top had over 100 proposed changes.

So I propose the way you review is the same, but it gets turned into a queue/s. So we should add audits, a Skip button. We shouldn't add a reputation amount you need to review (like we don't now). If we had multiple queues, we would have them for Edits and New Topics. If anywone has any other ideas, please feel free to comment or edit this post.